# Android - Open GL ES ... Where can i start with?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Can anyone suggest me the best place to start with for learning Open GL ES .... some good tutorial site or some pdf .....

Comment: My blog: http://p-xr.com has a OpenGL starters tutorial. More will be put up in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with OpenGL... in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469833/getting-started-with-opengl-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Getting started with OpenGL... in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469833/getting-started-with-opengl-in-android)

[Pro Android Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226471)

[Beginning Android Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230428)

Also check Related Links regarding to your question, which are bottom right of your question.

Answer (score 0):

find a book called "opengl super bible". it's probably the best resource on opengl out there